# Is it possible to put a system of equations parallel to the matrix?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

$4T_1-T_2 - T_4 = 30$
$-T_1+4T_2 -T_3 = 60$
$-T_2 + 4T_3 + T_4 = 70$
$-T_1 + T_3 + 4T_4 = 40$

Is it possible to put the above system of equations parallel to right side of the below matrix?

$
\begin{bmatrix}  
 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 30 \\  
-1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & 60 \\   
 0 & -1 & 4 & 1 & 70 \\  
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 40 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

{Finished]

$\begin{array}{rcl} 
4T_1-T_2 - T_4 &=& 30 \\
 -T_1+4T_2 -T_3 &=& 60\\ 
-T_2 + 4T_3 - T_4 &=& 70\\
 -T_1 - T_3 + 4T_4 &=& 40\\
 \end{array} \qquad 
\begin{bmatrix} 
4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 30 \\ 
-1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & 60 \\ 
0 & -1 & 4 & -1 & 70 \\ 
-1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 40 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \space
 \begin{array}{rcl} 
R_1 &↔& R_4 \\
 R_2 &↔&R_3 \\ \\ \\ \end{array} $

Comment: you want to put them on the same "line"?

Comment: You can use `\begin{array}` for that, but it might be simpler to use `\begin{cases}` to build your system of equations and then put it in the same `$$...$$` as your `\begin{bmatrix}`.

Comment: @Surb Sort of. The system takes 4 lines, so does the matrix. I want to align them side by side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, note that your system of equation can be written in a "better" way:
Indeed,

> `\begin{array}{rcl} a+b & = & c \\ d+e & = & i\end{array}`

will produce
$$\begin{array}{rcl} a+b & = & c \\ d+e & = & i\end{array}$$
Now, with

> `\begin{array}{rcl} a+b & = & c \\ d+e& = & i\end{array} \qquad \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ d & e \end{bmatrix}`

(where the `\qquad` is just here for spacing) you will get 
$$\begin{array}{rcl} a+b &=& c \\ d+e&=& i\end{array} \qquad \qquad \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ d & e \end{bmatrix}$$
Finally, note that to write your system, you can also use `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`, that is, with

> `\begin{cases}a+b = c \\ d+e= i\end{cases}`

you'll get
$$\begin{cases}a+b = c \\ d+e= i\end{cases}$$

Comment: It would be also possible to put systems and matrices into another array. For example, like this:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{rcl} x+y & = & 1 \\ x-y& = & 1\end{array} & \left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 &-1 & 1  \end{array}\right)\\\hline
\begin{array}{rcl} x+y & = & 1 \\ 2x& = & 2\end{array} & \left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 2  \end{array}\right)
\end{array}$$
It might be useful if you want to illustrate multiple steps in this way.

Comment: it is probably better to use `\begin{align}...\end{align}` for a system than to use the `array` environment.  The spacing around the equal sign will be better.  Note that `align` only needs an ampersand *before* the equals, not one after.  Finally, to do your mixed alignment and matrix, use `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The `amsmath` functionality is available in MathJaX, so you can do, e.g.,

> `$\newcommand{\9}{\phantom{9}}$
>   $$
> \begin{alignedat}{3}
> 4T_1 &- \9 T_2 &&- \9 T_4 &&= 30, \\
> -T_1 &+  4 T_2 &&- \9 T_3 &&= 60, \\
> -T_2 &+  4 T_3 &&+ \9 T_4 &&= 70, \\
> -T_1 &+ \9 T_3 &&+  4 T_4 &&= 40;
> \end{alignedat}\qquad\qquad
> \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr@{}}
>  4 & -1 &  0 & -1 & 30 \\  
> -1 &  4 & -1 &  0 & 60 \\   
>  0 & -1 &  4 &  1 & 70 \\  
> -1 &  0 &  1 &  4 & 40 \\
> \end{array}\right].
> $$`

to obtain
$\newcommand{\9}{\phantom{9}}$
$$
\begin{alignedat}{3}
4T_1 &- \9 T_2 &&- \9 T_4 &&= 30, \\
-T_1 &+  4 T_2 &&- \9 T_3 &&= 60, \\
-T_2 &+  4 T_3 &&+ \9 T_4 &&= 70, \\
-T_1 &+ \9 T_3 &&+  4 T_4 &&= 40;
\end{alignedat}\qquad\qquad
\left[\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr@{}}
 4 & -1 &  0 & -1 & 30 \\  
-1 &  4 & -1 &  0 & 60 \\   
 0 & -1 &  4 &  1 & 70 \\  
-1 &  0 &  1 &  4 & 40 \\
\end{array}\right].
$$